# Is it legal to short a company's stock and then blog about why you did it?

Tags: united-states, defamation, libel, securities, sec

In America, is it legal to short a company with which I never had any affiliation and then write a negative blog post about it affecting the company's stock price?

More specifically, suppose everything in this blog post is accurate, but kind of difficult to prove. Experts are needed to determine the truth, and the experts are, say, 9:1 in favor vs against it being true.

Can this company drag me through the courts for libel? Is there any kind of SEC violation possible here (stock manipulation, or something)?

Comment: feel free to add relevant tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If you plan to defend defamation with truth, the onus is on you to prove truth

Because truth is an affirmative defence, the onus is on the defendant to prove it, not on the prosecution to prove falsehood.

You mention in a comment that the CTO “admitted fraud”. If you were to accuse the CTO or the company of fraud (a crime, so defamation per see) you would have to prove it - ideally by pointing to the court judgement that convicted them. Or, by bringing successful criminal charges yourself. Fraud is not just a set of facts - it’s a set of facts that have been tested in court and resulted in a conviction.

Of course, if you just detail the facts without drawing the fraud conclusion then so long as you can prove each and every one is true, you can successfully defend a defamation case. Expert testimony may be relevant but 9:1 in your favour is not necessarily going to convince the court - they may find the 1 more compelling than the 9.

Answer (score 4):

As long as what you are posting is factual, public knowledge then you shouldn't be in violation of any SEC rules. Short-selling in-and-of itself is perfectly legal, so is exercising your right to free speech, in so far as the things you say are true and known. Now if you made up some story about Musk and it caused the stock to fall where you gain, this could be a violation. Likewise if you have come to be in possession of private knowledge and blog about that, you could be in violation of SEC rules.

Comment: What constitutes  "public knowledge"? Suppose the CTO emailed me and said something that made me think the company is overvalued.

Comment: That is privileged information if it isn't publicly released. In that case, the CTO can also be guilty.

Comment: So, in practical terms, the CTO can never say anything? What actually happened, is I contacted the CTO and his answers were shady (To my mind, he admitted fraud)

Comment: ...he's a "public source" in the sense that anyone else could have contacted him with the same questions, no?

Comment: @MaxB No. "[All information about the Company is considered nonpublic information until it is disseminated in a manner calculated to reach the securities marketplace through recognized channels of distribution and public investors have had a reasonable period of time to react to the information. Generally, information which has not been available to the investing public for at least two (2) full business days is considered to be nonpublic.](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/25743/000138713113000737/ex14_02.htm)"

Comment: (cont) that's just an example from a filing by one company, but typical of the agreements signed by corporate officers.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant But company executives generally talk to people outside of the company (without releasing their words to all of the public). Chances are that those words carry some meaning to other people that might be relevant to how they value the company's stock. This would imply that whenever the executives talk to anyone non-publicly they are guilty of some securities violation?

Comment: @MaxB, no it means that company officers have to watch what they say very carefully, or they can be accused of a number of securities violations. That's why officers in publicly traded companies typically keep logs of all their telephone calls and visitors. Note that at this very minute Elon Musk is under SEC sanctions for careless blabbing on Twitter.